# R, Spatial clustering by value

Tags: r, optimization, cluster-analysis, spatial

I have this simple dataset. The dataset is by hypothetical geographical unit (i.e. postal code) and has 3 variables: longitude, latitude and someValue (sales).

`lon<-rep(1:10,each=10)
lat<-rep(1:10,10)
someValue<-rnorm(100, mean = 20, sd = 5)
dataset<-data.frame(lon,lat,someValue)`

The problem I’m facing is territory alignment. Given a proposed number of territories I need to group postal codes into territories in such a way that the territories consist of adjacent postal codes and the sum of someValue is roughly the same (+/- 15% of the average for the specified number of territories)

The best idea I have at this point is to: 1. do clustering on lon/lat first to establish candidates; 2. do clustering on someValue using centroids from step 1 as centers with iter.max=1; 3 iterate over 1 and 2 until some convergence cut-off.

I would like to ask the community: what would be a proper methodology to implement something like this in R? I did search for Spatial Clustering and was not able to find anything relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the clustering using `kmeans` by only considering the first two columns (x and y):

```
#How Many cluster do you want to have initially?
initialClasses <- 2

#clustering using kmeans
initClust            <- kmeans(dataset[,1:2], initialClasses, iter.max = 100)
dataset$classes <- initClust$cluster
```

`initClust$cluster` then contains your cluster classes. You can add them to your dataframe and use dplyr to calculate some statistics. For example to sum of `someValue` per cluster:

```
library(dplyr)
statistics      <- dataset %>% group_by(classes) %>%summarize(sum=sum(someValue))
```

Here for example the sum of `someValue` over two classes:

```
  classes      sum
    (int)    (dbl)
1       1 975.7783
2       2 978.9166
```

Let's say your data is equally distributed and you want the sum of someValue per cluster to be smaller. Then you need to rerun the clustering with more (i.e. 3) classes:

```
newRun            <- kmeans(dataset[,1:2], 3, iter.max = 100)
dataset$classes <- newRun$cluster
```

Here the output statistics for three classes:

```
  classes      sum
    (int)    (dbl)
1       1 577.6573
2       2 739.9668
3       3 637.0707
```

By wrapping this inside a loop and calculating more criteria (i.e. variance) you can tune your clustering into the right size. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @maRtin . The problem is that I have the number of territories/cluster predetermined beforehand. I need to form clusters that contain similar total for the Value. That is the value across 100 postal codes is 100*$20=$2000 and I need 10 territories. That means I need to create territories that are approximately $200 in value